# Karate JDBC Connection

Tags: karate, web-api-testing

In Karate script is there a way to cache the DB connections ? . To be more specific the DB connections are through a Java program , every time we make DB calls the connection call is also

- def dbDemo=Java.type('tests.DataBaseAssertions')

The above line of code is used in all the feature files . Is there a way to cache this object so that all script can refer to that .

Application level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for the `callSingle()` syntax, please refer to the docs:

https://github.com/intuit/karate#hooks

```
var result = karate.callSingle('classpath:jdbc.feature');
```

Comment: What is the option to close all open connections once the tests are complete ?

Comment: @Ramath there is no global `afterSuite` hook. you don't need one. your connections should die with the JVM exit

Comment: @Ramath - one more thing, for others who may refer this answer in the future - if you really want to run some custom code *after* a test-suite run, do it via the `@AfterClass` annotation or equivalent annotation in JUnit.

Comment: My worry was all the DB connections are left open without closing , don't you think we need to close these open connections as a best practice ?

Comment: @Ramath it is up to you. see my comment above. it comes down to how you have implemented your JDBC code. this has nothing to do with karate

Comment: Oh I see your comment now thanks @Peter . One more question is there a way to run a script to run at the end as a clean up ?

Comment: @Ramath already answered in the first 2 comments I made above. Java code yes. if by "script" you mean Karate feature, the answer is no. you can always use the Java API. my advice - just use Java for these complex things (BTW no one has EVER asked for this feature, you are the first)

Comment: I'm thinking of creating a tag in feature file for Cleanup , Is the tag execution is happening in an order we specify . @CucumberOptions(tags = {"integration,Cleanup", "~ignore"}) , in this case will the Cleanup get executed after integration tag?

Comment: @Ramath no it is not executed in that order